# How can I use <% link %> tag inside javascript code. I am using Phoenix Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, elixir, font-awesome, phoenix-framework

I am creating Web Application using Phoenix Framework. I want to dynamically add `<% link %>` tag, and inside it put Font Awesome Icon in JavaScript file. How can I achieve this? I want something like that:

```
let data = '<%= link to: Routes.session_path(@conn, :delete), method: :delete do %><%= tag(:i, class: "fas fa-sign-out-alt") %><% end %>';
$('#target-div').html(data);
```

Comment: When you view the result in your browser's page source, what is the generated JavaScript code?  It sounds like this could be as simple as just wrapping your string in quotes.

Comment: Yes, of course.```<div id="target-div">&lt;%= link to: Routes.session_path(@conn, :delete), method: :delete do %&gt;&lt;%= tag(:i, class: "fas fa-sign-out-alt") %&gt;&lt;% end %&gt;</div>```

Comment: From the look of that output, your server side code has not been interpreted. Are you trying to run this code in a .js file?

Comment: Yes, in the ```socket.js``` file

Comment: It needs to be placed in a location that your server side code will run, ie. not in a .js file. I'd suggest outputting the string in your view and then passing that as an argument to a function in the .js file which performs whatever actions are necessary.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, e.g. I can use AJAX requests? And render the result?

Comment: That would work too, although is overkill if you already have access to the value when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks all of you for answers. How can I honor all of you? Is there "Like" or something like that button? I don't see